# Why has this question become hot twice within a few seconds of interval?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Why has this question become hot twice within a few seconds of interval? Is that expected to see this in the question log?

https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/52764/revisions

[image: image description here]

Comment: This question **is** slightly (greatly?) different from the claimed duplicate. The duplicate and it's others duplicates are for **multiple entry onto the hot questions list** ***simultaneously*** - this question is about [multiple entry **seconds apart**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/52764/timeline), so it doesn't appear to be the same; the computer isn't *that* slow. But, I'll leave it to Franck (or the Dev) to reopen this.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, good catch, I have no idea if that is the same bug or a different one then :/ I'll defer it to the developers!